# What does NetworkX return in single_source_dijkstra_path_length if there is no path

Tags: python, networkx

I have a digraph and am using NetworkX to find shortest lengths to all nodes from a node. To do this, I am using [single_source_dijkstra_path_length](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.weighted.single_source_dijkstra_path_length.html#networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.weighted.single_source_dijkstra_path_length). In the documentation, they say a NodeNotFound error is raised when the given node is not in the graph. But, I wonder what it outputs for a node that is not reachable (no path exists) from the given source.

Comment: How can it be not reachable?

Comment: Looking at [the source](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/_modules/networkx/algorithms/shortest_paths/weighted.html#single_source_dijkstra_path_length) it looks as though it returns an empty `dict` if no nodes are reachable.

Comment: See the answer for some inspiration :)

Comment: Some nodes may not be reachable because the graph is directed. Consider a dead end street.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The node is simply not contained in the returned dict:

```
import networkx as nx

g = nx.Graph()

g.add_nodes_from(range(3))
g.add_edge(1,2, weight=2)
print(nx.single_source_dijkstra_path_length(g, 1))
# {1: 0, 2: 2}
```

The algorithms with `source` and `target` will raise [`NetworkXNoPath`](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/blob/85d2db3558613704691eaa9c6715db85426b3c7a/networkx/exception.py#L60) ([docs](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/exceptions.html#networkx.NetworkXNoPath)) as you can see for example in the implementation of the undirected algorithms, [here](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/blob/85d2db3558613704691eaa9c6715db85426b3c7a/networkx/algorithms/shortest_paths/unweighted.py#L292), or [here](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/blob/85d2db3558613704691eaa9c6715db85426b3c7a/networkx/algorithms/shortest_paths/weighted.py#L235) for directed case. It is also in the documentation of [`dijkstra_path`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.weighted.dijkstra_path.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I also figured that out with your method after posting. Let's keep all here for future newbies!